# ListView loses all selections when DialogFragment is shown

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a fragment that contains a `ListView`, when I try to show a `DialogFragment` on the top of it the selected list items are deselected. Is it possible to keep the items selected when the `DialogFragment` appears/disappears?

**My Fragment's onCreateView():**

```
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "BrowserFragment.onCreateView()");
            }
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_filebrowser, container,
                    false);
            listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
            listView.setEmptyView(v.findViewById(android.R.id.empty));

            // FOR CONTEXT ACTION MENU
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                    MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                    inflater.inflate(R.menu.contexual, menu);
                    mode.setTitle("Choose Files");
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroyActionMode!");

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {

                    case R.id.menu_delete:

                        SimpleDialogFragment
                                .createBuilder(getActivity(),
                                        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager())
                                .setTitle(R.string.delete_files)
                                .setMessage(R.string.confirm_delete)
                                .setPositiveButtonText(R.string.yes)
                                .setNegativeButtonText(R.string.no).show();

               mode.finish();
    //The rest of the program..
```

**Screenshots:**

[image]
[image]

As you can see in the second screenshot, the listview's selected items have been deselected. How can I prevent that?

**UPDATE:** I'm using [StyledDialogs](https://github.com/inmite/android-styled-dialogs) library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution, the problem was that i was calling `mode.finish()` right after the `dialogfragment.show()`. I stored the `ActionMode` variable and used it inside my `DialogFragments` positive button callback to call the `.finish()` instead and everything is working correctly.